# Kernel Compiling Error in Virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, compiling

This is my first time using Virtualbox and anything to do with Linux and Ubuntu. I will try to be as precise and accurate with the information that I write.

I have installed Ubuntu version 16.04 within Virtualbox on Windows (Windows 7 running on 32 bit). After downloading and configuring kernel version 5.0.2, I tried using "sudo make" to compile my kernel.

However, either of two errors occur:

1. This is the first error:

   ```
   scripts/link-vmlinux.sh: line 85: 1847 killed DFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS_VMLINUX} -0 ${2} -T ${lds} ${objects}
   Makefile:1019: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
   make: *** [vmlinux] Error 137
   ```
2. And this is the second error:

   ```
   ld: final link failed: Memory exhausted
   Makefile:1019: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
   make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
   ```

From what I have gathered, this has to do with not enough virtual hard disk memory. Currently, I have set my vdi with 24GB, and its actual size is 15.15GB (dynamically allocated).

By using the `swapon -s` command, I can see that I have used 38400 out of 522236 for my `/dev/sda5` partition. No other files are listed. (By using the "free" command 483836 out of 522236 is free for the swap partition.)

By using the `df -h` command, after trying to compile my kernel, 13G out of 24G has been used.

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I found my way here so I thought I'd add some detail.

The issue is that the compiler (or, more precisely, the gnu linker) has run out of memory.  In my case I had allocated a meager 2GB to memory.  I increased the memory to 8GB and the compile completed without error.